# Scraping users video in Twitter with rvest

Tags: css, r, twitter, web-scraping, rvest

I'm using `rvest` to **scrape** some web static elements in the web. However, I could not scrape dynamic content . For example, how to scrape audience count (44K) in the following [video post](https://twitter.com/estrellagalicia/status/993432910584659968)?

[image]

I tried this:

```
library(rvest)
video_tweet = html("https://twitter.com/estrellagalicia/status/993432910584659968")
video_tweet %>% 
  html_nodes("#permalink-overlay #permalink-overlay-dialog div #permalink-overlay-body div div div div div div div div div div div div span div div div div span span") %>% as.character()
```

Comment: You need to use Rselenium. You should read some Rselenium Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Rselenium and you should pick the right css for it.This should work:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
rmDr <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
myclient <- rmDr$client
video_tweet = "https://twitter.com/estrellagalicia/status/993432910584659968"

myclient$navigate(video_tweet)

mypagesource <- myclient$getPageSource()
read_html(mypagesource[[1]]) %>% 
    html_nodes("#permalink-overlay-dialog > div.PermalinkOverlay-content > div > div > div.permalink.light-inline-actions.stream-uncapped.has-replies.original-permalink-page > div.permalink-inner.permalink-tweet-container > div > div.js-tweet-details-fixer.tweet-details-fixer > div.card2.js-media-container.has-autoplayable-media > div.PlayableMedia.LiveBroadcastCard-playerContainer.LiveBroadcastCard--supportsLandscapePresentation.watched.playable-media-loaded > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.rn-1oszu61.rn-1efd50x.rn-14skgim.rn-rull8r.rn-mm0ijv.rn-13yce4e.rn-fnigne.rn-ndvcnb.rn-gxnn5r.rn-1nlw0im.rn-deolkf.rn-6koalj.rn-1pxmb3b.rn-7vfszb.rn-eqz5dr.rn-1r74h94.rn-1mnahxq.rn-61z16t.rn-p1pxzi.rn-11wrixw.rn-ifefl9.rn-bcqeeo.rn-wk8lta.rn-9aemit.rn-1mdbw0j.rn-gy4na3.rn-u8s1d.rn-1lgpqti > span > div > div.rn-1oszu61.rn-1efd50x.rn-14skgim.rn-rull8r.rn-mm0ijv.rn-13yce4e.rn-fnigne.rn-ndvcnb.rn-gxnn5r.rn-deolkf.rn-6koalj.rn-1pxmb3b.rn-7vfszb.rn-eqz5dr.rn-1mnahxq.rn-61z16t.rn-p1pxzi.rn-11wrixw.rn-ifefl9.rn-bcqeeo.rn-wk8lta.rn-9aemit.rn-1mdbw0j.rn-gy4na3.rn-bnwqim.rn-1lgpqti > div > div > span > span") %>% as.character()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I had an issue with RSelenium, after running rsDriver(): "Please ensure a Selenium server is running". Should I install some plugings to chrome (like Phantom)?

Comment: I never ran into that problem before. Have you tried to search for the solutions?